# How to find if duplicate document exist in MongoDB collection using java?

Tags: java, mongodb

The goal is to insert documents, each consisted of several fields, into a collection in Mongo database, insert is performed if no other document with the exact same fields (except "_id") was found, otherwise, it should throw an exception and catch it, printing error. I am having some trouble finding the right way to "find" such duplicate with mongodb on java.

```
Document zeroCmd = new Document();
zeroCmd.put("name", item[1]);
zeroCmd.put("supplier", item[2]);
zeroCmd.put("food", item[3]);
zeroCmd.put("country of origin", item[4]);
Bson filter = Filters.and(
        Filters.eq("name", item[1]),
        Filters.eq("supplier", item[2]),
        Filters.eq("food", item[3]),
        Filters.eq("country of origin", item[4])
        );

// This line causes problem most cuz I am not sure how to identify the result returned
// by finOne() as the Oracle says it was interface. It got me confused
DBObject duplicate = match.findOne(filter);
try {
// So, I am not sure if null is the right catch if NO matching document was found from database
    if (duplicate != null) {
        InsertOneResult result = match.insertOne(zeroCmd);
    }
    throw new Exception("[Error] duplicate insertion");
} catch (Exception me) {
    System.out.println(me.getMessage());
}
break;
```

Please let me know what do you guys think.

Thank you!

```
Document zeroCmd = new Document();
zeroCmd.put("name", item[1]);
zeroCmd.put("supplier", item[2]);
zeroCmd.put("food", item[3]);
zeroCmd.put("country of origin", item[4]);
Bson filter = Filters.and(
        Filters.eq("name", item[1]),
        Filters.eq("supplier", item[2]),
        Filters.eq("food", item[3]),
        Filters.eq("country of origin", item[4])
        );

// This line causes problem most cuz I am not sure how to identify the result returned
// by finOne() as the Oracle says it was interface. It got me confused
DBObject duplicate = match.findOne(filter);
try {
// So, I am not sure if null is the right catch if NO matching document was found from database
    if (duplicate != null) {
        InsertOneResult result = match.insertOne(zeroCmd);
    }
    throw new Exception("[Error] duplicate insertion");
} catch (Exception me) {
    System.out.println(me.getMessage());
}
break;
```

Comment: Why did you post your source code twice? Is there a difference? Also, you want to insert a document when it is not already there. In your code you insert it only if there is a matching document. findOne() returns null if there is no document (see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/)

Answer (score 0):

The `_id` field is present in all documents in the collection - it is mandatory.

If the `_id` is not supplied by the application / user, `MongoDB` will create it when the document is inserted (and it will be of `type ObjectId`).

The `_id` value has a **default unique index** on it - this is automatically created by `MongoDB`. So, a collection can have **only one document** with a specific `_id`. Also, the `_id` value **cannot be modified** for a document, and the unique index on this field cannot be deleted (or modified).